# How can I solve a 'reboot and select a proper boot device' error after an installation from a live CD?

Tags: 12.04, boot

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 from a live CD. Ubuntu 12.04 is the only operating system on my pc.

My boot settings in the BIOS are:

1. boot device CD
2. boot device hard drive.

I installed Ubuntu without any problems. BUT my system will not boot without my live CD.

Every time I try it says :

> Reboot and select a proper boot device.

What should I do? I ran a boot repair and I have the URL to paste here http://paste.ubuntu.com/1476459/.

Comment: Hi tzhou. What is your hardware?

Answer (score 1):

You should try making the hard drive the primary boot device if you want to boot from it instead of the CD. Set 1 to HDD, and 2 to CD and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: no difference. i made it a lot of times :)

Comment: Most computers will bypass the CD drive anyways if it's empty. Can you give us more details on what exactly it's saying? Also, is the bios saying it or is it a message from the OS itself?

Comment: Reboot and select proper boot device. or insert boot media in the selected boot device and press enter.     That is what it is saying. i dont know where it came from Os or bios

Comment: I've actually experienced that before. My experience it was from the bios and it was because I had accidentally erased the bootloader of my harddrive.

Comment: hmm so what i should do?

Comment: Check to make sure the partition Ubuntu is installed on is bootable. Make sure the bootloader is properly installed. If not, you may have to reinstall your bootloader.

Comment: i reinstalled the grub loader. but nothing happened.

Comment: Is the partition set to bootable? I believe you can have a bootloader but unless the partition itself actually tells the computer it's bootable, bios will ignore it.

Comment: how can i see is the partition is bootable? how can i make it bootable?

Comment: open gparted in a livecd and look at the flags section of your harddrive. Make sure there is a boot flag.

Comment: if its not what should i make?